# Microsoft Word: {command|option} + delete behaviour on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

The behaviour of the sequences <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> are annoyingly inconsistent using Word 2011 for Mac.

If the character after the cursor is a space, then the key combinations above will delete the word before the cursor, **and the space before that word**. However, if the character after the cursor is *not* a space, then the key combination above will delete **only the previous word**. For example (where '|' is the cursor position):

```
This is a | sentence
```

after the key sequence:

```
This is| sentence
```

However, in this situation:

```
This is a |sentence
```

after the key sequence:

```
 This is |sentence
```

I **never** want to delete the space before the word immediately before the cursor using the key combination <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>. So, in this situation:

```
This is a | sentence
```

I *always* want the key sequence to result in this:

```
This is | sentence
```

#### This is the behaviour on every other Mac program!

Textedit, for example, exhibits the behaviour I want. Word (and all programs I've checked in the Microsoft Office suite) are non-standard with the behaviour I do not want.

How can I change the Word keystroke behaviour?